# can the adhesive used in thru-glass antenna couplers be replaced?

Tags: antenna, windows

I recently bought a pair of self-adhesive thru-glass antenna couplers for my mobile radios and erred in mounting both of them, which required me to peel them off the side window glass in my minivan. The doublestick tape compound used on them exhibited such terrific adhesion that it was ruined in the removal process. Is there any way that I can possibly re-use these antenna mounts?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. The protective tape that you peel off the mount before pressing it onto the window glass bears the emblem "3M", identifying it as a product of the 3M adhesives group. A web search then reveals that fresh 3M industrial strength indoor/outdoor doublestick tape can be bought in rolls and precut squares at hardware stores as "Scotchmount Extreme" double-sided mounting tape. This product is almost identical to the original material, and I used it to re-attach both antenna mounts in their correct positions on my van.

It is stout and weather-resistant enough that it can be used to attach license plates to car bumpers, and to attach chrome trim strips to automotive bodywork.